# Connecting to database via PHP and displaying contents on browser

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I am connecting to an SQL server via PHP script and displaying the contents retrieved on the browser.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/trial/5.0.0/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-    
theme-neptune-all.css">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/php" src="connection.php"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    d3.json("connection.php", function (data) {
        document.write(data);
    });
});
```

connection.php

```
<?php

// Server Name
$myServer = "10.112.1.2";

// Database
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database"=>"logs", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo);
if (!$conn) {
    $message = "Connection failed";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
} else {
    $message = "Connected";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.logsData";
$data = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $data === false ) {
    echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$result = array(); 

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $result[] = $row; 
    }
} while ( sqlsrv_next_result($data) );

echo json_encode($result);

sqlsrv_free_stmt($data);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

All 3 files are in the same folder.
The browser just displays a null and I don't hit any of the logging information from the .php file. Is my method right? Am I using the right javascript event?

Comment: Wrap everything in a try/catch (http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) which will tell you if your php.ini settings are hiding some errors.

Comment: Everything else looks fine? How do I test the connection alone?

Comment: Use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) if you just want to inspect the value(s) associated with your connection object.

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection.php in this way:

```
    if (!$conn) {
    $message = "Connection failed";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
}
```

You need to change mime type of your response. Moreover you cannot print out anything else than json data. That's way I removed from your code these lines:

```
    $message = "Connected";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a relative pathname for connection.php here: *d3.json("**connection**.**php**"*

Something like "/dirname/connection.php".

You can test connection.php alone using a full pathname, like http://www.yourserver.xxx/dirname1/dirname2/...connection.php

Comment: What about testing connection.php alone?